# Register & Login code does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a login/register system like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til3oVNlho4&index=7&list=PLE134D877783367C7, but the problem is that it is using Mysql rather than Mysqli functions which makes it almost impossible to understand to me as a beginner. Basically, I`m stuck at database checking if "user_exists" function. Would anyone be able to point me to the right direction?

```
<?php


function user_exists($username) {
    include 'core/database/connect.php';
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0) {
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){

        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);

        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

        if (isset($resrow[$col])) {
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Then I`m doing a check if that user exists:

```
if (user_exists('bill') === true) {
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'not ok';
}
```

It is always returning as not true even if the user is in my database.

Comment: looks like you did not define database connection. you are using $db in $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql); but $db does not exist. can you please provide result of var_dump($query); ?

Answer (score 0):

The condition for `$numrows` always evaluates to 0. Therefore it returns false and hence not true.

Comment: Could You maybe correct the code for me the way You see fit?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function user_exists($username) {
  include 'core/database/connect.php';
  $username = sanitize($username);
  $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE username = '{$username}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  return $num_rows > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Try that, you don't need second function. This piece of code does not check for validation or implements try/catch blocks. I modified your SQL statement because you just need to see if the result returned anything higher than zero results.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, but it still returns as false always... I`ve lost my hope, I think I`ll just abandon the project for some time.

Comment: If you run your SQL statement directly in the DB, do you get any results for the test username? If yes, if you do var_dump($result); what do you see?